# Dagger Classes showing up as red but still builds

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

I am new to Dagger2 and I am trying to use it in my Kotlin project (1.1.51).  I followed a few tutorials and all is good.

I have these in my gradle file and I am using Android Studio 3.01, I have to use gradle-3.3

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-allopen'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

 compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
 kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

I can successfully run my project and Dagger2 seems to be working.  The only annoying issue is that the Dagger created classes always come up as red on the import list. e.g DaggerMainComponent.

import com.burfdevelopment.hack24.Dagger.MainComponent
import com.burfdevelopment.hack24.Dagger.MainModule
import com.burfdevelopment.hack24.Dagger.**DaggerMainComponent**

So if do a code tidy which removes unused imports it always removes it even though its being used. If I click on the DaggerMainComponent, it does go to the generated class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there's an issue with the configured folders in Android Studio. In particular, in your `build.gradle` file you should have something like this (I used it in my IntelliJ Idea projects, but it should work also in Android Studio):

```
// Configure Dagger generated files
ideaModule.module.generatedSourceDirs += file("$buildDir/generated/source/kapt/main")
```

In this way, you are telling your IDE to mark as "generated sources", the source files under that folder (which is where Kapt puts generated files like your `DaggerMainComponent`)